Dropping the redPieces in vertical orientation


// Function to create grid
function createGrid(containerId, numRows, numCols, colorClass) {
  const gridContainer = document.getElementById(containerId);
  for (let i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
    const row = document.createElement('div');
    row.classList.add('row');
    for (let j = 0; j < numCols; j++) {
      const square = document.createElement('div');
      square.classList.add('square', colorClass);
      // Enable dropping on the square
      square.setAttribute('ondrop', 'drop(event)');
      square.setAttribute('ondragover', 'allowDrop(event)');
      row.appendChild(square);
    }
    gridContainer.appendChild(row);
  }
}

function allowDrop(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
}

// Function to add drag and drop functionality to redPieces
function addDragDrop(redPieceId) {
  const redPiece = document.getElementById(redPieceId);
  redPiece.setAttribute('draggable', true);
  redPiece.addEventListener('dragstart', (event) => {
    event.dataTransfer.setData('text', event.target.id);
  });
}

// Add drag and drop functionality to all redPieces
const redPieceIds = ['redPiece5', 'redPiece4', 'redPiece3-1', 'redPiece3-2', 'redPiece2'];
redPieceIds.forEach((redPieceId) => {
  addDragDrop(redPieceId);
});


function drop(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  const data = event.dataTransfer.getData('text');
  const draggableElement = document.getElementById(data);
  const target = event.target;
  // Check if the target is a grid square and doesn't have child nodes
  if (target.classList.contains('square') && target.childElementCount === 0) {
    // console.log('Dropped redPiece5 into square:', target);

    let emptySquareCount = 1; // Initialize with 1 to include the dropped square itself
    let prevSquare = target.previousElementSibling;
    // Count the number of empty grid squares before the dropped square
    while (prevSquare && prevSquare.childElementCount === 0) {
      emptySquareCount++;
      prevSquare = prevSquare.previousElementSibling;
    }

    // Move the second and subsequent children based on emptySquareCount
    if (emptySquareCount <= 1) {
      // Move the second and subsequent children to the next grid squares
      let nextSquare = target.nextElementSibling;
      for (let i = 1; i < draggableElement.children.length; i++) {
        // Check if there are no more adjacent squares
        if (!nextSquare || nextSquare.childElementCount > 0) {
          break;
        }
        const child = draggableElement.children[i].cloneNode(true);
        nextSquare.appendChild(child);
        nextSquare = nextSquare.nextElementSibling;
      }
    } else {
      // Move the second and subsequent children to the previous and next grid squares
      prevSquare = target.previousElementSibling;
      let nextSquare = target.nextElementSibling;
      for (let i = 1; i < draggableElement.children.length; i++) {
        // Move the child to the previous square if available
        if (prevSquare && prevSquare.childElementCount === 0) {
          const child = draggableElement.children[i].cloneNode(true);
          prevSquare.appendChild(child);
          prevSquare = prevSquare.previousElementSibling;
        }
        // Move the child to the next square if available
        else if (nextSquare && nextSquare.childElementCount === 0) {
          const child = draggableElement.children[i].cloneNode(true);
          nextSquare.appendChild(child);
          nextSquare = nextSquare.nextElementSibling;
        }
      }
    }

    // Append the original div (with only one child) to the target
    const originalChild = draggableElement.children[0];
    target.appendChild(originalChild);

    // Remove redPiece5 from redPieces div
    const redPiecesDiv = document.getElementById('redPieces');
    redPiecesDiv.removeChild(draggableElement);
  }
}

// Define the number of rows and columns
const rows = 7;
const columns = 9;

// Create red grid
createGrid('redGrid', rows, columns, 'red');

// Create blue grid
createGrid('blueGrid', rows, columns, 'blue');

// Function to rotate the pieces
function rotatePieces() {
  const squares = document.querySelectorAll('.square');
  squares.forEach((square) => {
    square.classList.toggle('vertical');
  });
  const redPiecesContainer = document.getElementById('redPieces');
  redPiecesContainer.classList.toggle('vertical');
}

// Event listener for the rotate button
const redRotate = document.getElementById('redRotate');
redRotate.addEventListener('click', rotatePieces);
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh; 
  margin: 0; 
}

#wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: row; 
  width: 100%; 
}

.colourContainer{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: row; 
}

.piecesBox {
  width: 210px;
  height: 210px;
  border: 1px dashed black;
}

.gridContainer {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  gap: 30px;
}

.grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 3px; 
  margin: 10px;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  gap: 3px;
}

.square {
  width: 30px; 
  height: 30px; 
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.red {
  background-color: crimson; 
}

.blue {
  background-color: royalblue; 
}

.green {
  background-color: green; 
}

.yellow {
  background-color: rgb(241, 241, 14); 
}

#greenPieces, #yellowPieces {
  display: none;
}
.lightcoral {
  background-color: lightcoral;
}

.piecesBox{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column; 
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.redPieceses{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: row; 
  margin: 5px;
  margin-block: 2px;
}
.bluePieceses{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: row; 
  margin: 5px;
  margin-block: 2px;
}

.pieceses{
  margin-right: 3px;
}

#redPiece5{
  order: 4;
}
#redPiece4{
  order: 5;
}
#redPiece3-1{
  order: 2;
}
#redPiece3-2{
  order: 3;
}
#redPiece2{
  order: 1;
}

#bluePiece5{
  order: 4;
}
#bluePiece4{
  order: 5;
}
#bluePiece3-1{
  order: 2;
}
#bluePiece3-2{
  order: 3;
}
#bluePiece2{
  order: 1;
}

.vertical {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.vertical #redPieces {
  flex-direction: column;
}
/* #redRotate.vertical {
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
} */
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Grid Example</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles/main.css">
</head>
<body>


  <div id="wrapper">


    
    <div class="gridContainer">


      <div id="redContainer" class="colourContainer">
        <div id="redPieces" class="piecesBox">
          <div id="redPiece5" class="redPieceses" draggable="true">
            <div class="square lightcoral pieceses"></div>
            <div class="square lightcoral pieceses"></div>
            <div class="square lightcoral pieceses"></div>
            <div class="square lightcoral pieceses"></div>
            <div class="square lightcoral pieceses"></div>
          </div> <button id="redRotate">Rotate</button>
        
          <div id="redPiece4" class="redPieceses" draggable="true">
            <div class="square lightcoral pieceses"></div>
            <div class="square lightcoral pieceses"></div>
            <div class="square lightcoral pieceses"></div>
            <div class="square lightcoral pieceses"></div>
          </div>
        
          <div id="redPiece3-1" class="redPieceses" draggable="true">
            <div class="square lightcoral pieceses"></div>
            <div class="square lightcoral pieceses"></div>
            <div class="square lightcoral pieceses"></div>
          </div>
        
          <div id="redPiece3-2" class="redPieceses" draggable="true">
            <div class="square lightcoral pieceses"></div>
            <div class="square lightcoral pieceses"></div>
            <div class="square lightcoral pieceses"></div>
          </div>
        
          <div id="redPiece2" class="redPieceses" draggable="true">
            <div class="square lightcoral pieceses"></div>
            <div class="square lightcoral pieceses"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid" id="redGrid"></div>
      </div>

      <div id="blueContainer" class="colourContainer">
        <div class="grid" id="blueGrid"></div>
        <div id="bluePieces" class="piecesBox">
          <div id="bluePiece5" class="bluePieceses" draggable="true">
            <div class="square blue pieceses"></div>
            <div class="square blue pieceses"></div>
            <div class="square blue pieceses"></div>
            <div class="square blue pieceses"></div>
            <div class="square blue pieceses"></div>
          </div>
        
          <div id="bluePiece4" class="bluePieceses" draggable="true">
            <div class="square blue pieceses"></div>
            <div class="square blue pieceses"></div>
            <div class="square blue pieceses"></div>
            <div class="square blue pieceses"></div>
          </div>
        
          <div id="bluePiece3-1" class="bluePieceses" draggable="true">
            <div class="square blue pieceses"></div>
            <div class="square blue pieceses"></div>
            <div class="square blue pieceses"></div>
          </div>
        
          <div id="bluePiece3-2" class="bluePieceses" draggable="true"> 
            <div class="square blue pieceses"></div>
            <div class="square blue pieceses"></div>
            <div class="square blue pieceses"></div>
          </div>
        
          <div id="bluePiece2" class="bluePieceses" draggable="true">
            <div class="square blue pieceses"></div>
            <div class="square blue pieceses"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- <div class="grid" id="greenGrid"></div>
      <div class="grid" id="yellowGrid"></div> -->
    </div>



  </div>

  <script src="./scripts/main.js"></script>

</body>
</html>



The above snippet only includes Horzitonal dropping.
When the pieces are horizontal, use the existing drop function, but when it is vertical add a drop that adds pieces into the grid in vertical positioning. So for adding I gave row class. which is the parent of the dropping grid piece. You can see in the HTML. so when it is vertical, we will add the next piece in the same element index but in the next row. Use if-else for toggling and drop
    // Function to create grid
function createGrid(containerId, numRows, numCols, colorClass) {
  const gridContainer = document.getElementById(containerId);
  for (let i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
    const row = document.createElement('div');
    row.classList.add('row');
    for (let j = 0; j < numCols; j++) {
      const square = document.createElement('div');
      square.classList.add('square', colorClass);
      // Enable dropping on the square
      square.setAttribute('ondrop', 'drop(event)');
      square.setAttribute('ondragover', 'allowDrop(event)');
      row.appendChild(square);
    }
    gridContainer.appendChild(row);
  }
}

function allowDrop(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
}

// Function to add drag and drop functionality to redPieces
function addDragDrop(redPieceId) {
  const redPiece = document.getElementById(redPieceId);
  redPiece.setAttribute('draggable', true);
  redPiece.addEventListener('dragstart', (event) => {
    event.dataTransfer.setData('text', event.target.id);
  });
}

// Add drag and drop functionality to all redPieces
const redPieceIds = ['redPiece5', 'redPiece4', 'redPiece3-1', 'redPiece3-2', 'redPiece2'];
redPieceIds.forEach((redPieceId) => {
  addDragDrop(redPieceId);
});

function drop(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  const data = event.dataTransfer.getData('text');
  const draggableElement = document.getElementById(data);
  const target = event.target;

  // Check if the redRotate button is in vertical position
  const isVertical = redRotate.classList.contains('vertical');

  // If in horizontal position, use the existing drop function
  if (!isVertical) {
    // Check if the target is a grid square and doesn't have child nodes
    if (target.classList.contains('square') && target.childElementCount === 0) {
      const originalChild = draggableElement.children[0].cloneNode(true);
      target.appendChild(originalChild);
      draggableElement.removeChild(originalChild);

      // Remove redPiece element if all children are dropped
      if (draggableElement.childElementCount === 0) {
        const redPiecesDiv = document.getElementById('redPieces');
        redPiecesDiv.removeChild(draggableElement);
      }
    }
  } else {
    // If in vertical position, add the piece to the grid vertically
    if (target.classList.contains('row')) {
      const row = target;
      const squares = row.querySelectorAll('.square');
      let emptySquare = null;
      squares.forEach(square => {
        if (square.childElementCount === 0 && emptySquare === null) {
          emptySquare = square;
        }
      });

      // If an empty square is found, drop the piece
      if (emptySquare !== null) {
        const originalChild = draggableElement.children[0].cloneNode(true);
        emptySquare.appendChild(originalChild);
        draggableElement.removeChild(originalChild);

        // Remove redPiece element if all children are dropped
        if (draggableElement.childElementCount === 0) {
          const redPiecesDiv = document.getElementById('redPieces');
          redPiecesDiv.removeChild(draggableElement);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}


// Define the number of rows and columns
const rows = 7;
const columns = 9;

// Create red grid
createGrid('redGrid', rows, columns, 'red');

// Create blue grid
createGrid('blueGrid', rows, columns, 'blue');

// Function to rotate the pieces
function rotatePieces() {
  const squares = document.querySelectorAll('.square');
  squares.forEach((square) => {
    square.classList.toggle('vertical');
  });
  const redPiecesContainer = document.getElementById('redPieces');
  redPiecesContainer.classList.toggle('vertical');
  // Toggle the class for the redRotate button
  redRotate.classList.toggle('vertical');
}

// Event listener for the rotate button
const redRotate = document.getElementById('redRotate');
redRotate.addEventListener('click', rotatePieces);

function drop(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  const data = event.dataTransfer.getData('text');
  const draggableElement = document.getElementById(data);
  const target = event.target;
  
  // Check if the redRotate button is in vertical position
  const isVertical = redRotate.classList.contains('vertical');

  // If in horizontal position, use the existing drop function
  if (!isVertical) {
    // Existing drop function logic
    // ...
  } else {
    // If in vertical position, add the piece to the grid vertically
    if (target.classList.contains('row')) {
      // Append the original div (with only one child) to the target row
      const originalChild = draggableElement.children[0];
      target.appendChild(originalChild);
    }
  }
}

 

I tried this in else for vertical but it does not work.
I think this method may work:
In horizontal dropping, I add the child to the next or previous element in the left or right. But here, adding  9 for the bottom and subtracting 9 for the top to the index will work.

You might want to add the html and css as well so it can be tested here.

Check now. You visited it before I added @Christian
